# How can I get standard errors for my 4 parameters when the Hessian matrix from solnp is 5 by 5?

Tags: r, hessian-matrix

I'm using the `solnp()` function in the R package **Rsolnp** to solve a nonlinear regression with constraints.  It works well, converges with no problem.  I want to use the Hessian matrix to calculate standard errors of the four parameter estimates, but the Hessian is not 4 by 4 as I had expected, but 5 by 5.  I looked around on SO and didn't see anyone else with an unexpected Hessian size.  All the examples I found with the Hessians printed showed them to be the expected size of p by p (e.g., [2x2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50264823), [3x3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494600), and [4x4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760500)).

How can I get standard errors for my 4 parameters from this 5 by 5 Hessian?

```
df <- data.frame(
  Recruit.N = c(78.4, 79.8, 106, 57.4, 81.7, 94.4, 74.1, 42, 61.6, 47.7, 61.8, 
    28.1, 32.3, 19, 23.4, 20.1, 27), 
  Stock.5 = c(66.6, 90.3, 138.5, 79.8, 77.3, 78.4, 79.8, 106, 57.4, 81.7, 94.4, 
    74.1, 42, 61.6, 47.7, 61.8, 28.1), 
  Stock.6 = c(25.2, 66.6, 90.3, 138.5, 79.8, 77.3, 78.4, 79.8, 106, 57.4, 81.7, 
    94.4, 74.1, 42, 61.6, 47.7, 61.8), 
  Stock.7 = c(23.8, 25.2, 66.6, 90.3, 138.5, 79.8, 77.3, 78.4, 79.8, 106, 57.4, 
    81.7, 94.4, 74.1, 42, 61.6, 47.7)
)

lossfcn <- function(parz, mydat) {
  alpha <- parz[[1]]
  beta <- parz[[2]]
  p5 <- parz[[3]]
  p6 <- parz[[4]]
  p7 <- 1 - p5 - p6
  S <- with(mydat, p5*Stock.5 + p6*Stock.6 + p7*Stock.7)
  Obs <- mydat$Recruit.N
  Pred <- alpha * S * exp(-beta*S)
  Resid <- log(Obs) - log(Pred)
  sigma <- sqrt(mean(Resid^2))
  LL <- dlnorm(Obs, meanlog=log(Pred), sdlog=sigma, log=TRUE)
  -sum(LL)
}

inequal <- function(parz, mydat) {
  parz[3] + parz[4]
}

library(Rsolnp)
solnp(pars=c(1, 0.008, 1/3, 1/3), fun=lossfcn, mydat=df,
  ineqfun=inequal, ineqLB=0, ineqUB=1, 
  LB=c(0, 0, 0, 0), UB=c(1000, 1000, 1, 1), control=list(trace=0))

$pars
[1] 6.731317e-01 1.888572e-10 8.141363e-01 1.858631e-01

$convergence
[1] 0

$values
[1] 79.87150 75.50927 75.50927 75.50927

$lagrange
          [,1]
[1,] -2.028222

$hessian
           [,1]          [,2]         [,3]        [,4]         [,5]
[1,]  0.3350868 -3.359077e-01     17.84919  -0.4306057   -0.3382811
[2,] -0.3359077  1.993956e+02 -10161.63351  -7.0844295   -2.2749785
[3,] 17.8491854 -1.016163e+04 548099.69224 -85.9544831 -224.0362766
[4,] -0.4306057 -7.084429e+00    -85.95448  25.1086694    5.8817704
[5,] -0.3382811 -2.274979e+00   -224.03628   5.8817704    4.1978178

$ineqx0
[1] 0.9999995

$nfuneval
[1] 142

$outer.iter
[1] 3

$elapsed
Time difference of 0.03016496 secs

$vscale
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the 3 posts you linked, you have an inequality constraint. Check the `ineqx0` in the returned values: the other posts have `NULL` but you have `0.9999995`. With an inequality constraint, there is a **slack variable**, so the problem is **augmented**. The hessian matrix returned is for this augmented set of parameters. Just retain the first 4 x 4 submatrix of the `hessian` for your wanted parameters.

Comment: To be sure I was targeting the right submatrix, I switched up the order of my parameters and discovered that the first row and column of the Hessian matrix correspond to the additional inequality parameter.  So, the submatrix corresponding to my original four parameters is `hessian[-1, -1]`.